# Server not responding after sending and receiving a few messages

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am trying to run a program having socket server implementation. The server is an application that transmits and receives messages two times. Third time when I try to transmit the message, the application hangs and server doesn't respond.

The output of the program is given below:

> 9300CN|CO|CP|AY1AZFAA4
>   220 SIP2Server@pid:50757
>   9300CN|CO|CP|AY1AZFAA4
>   940AY0AZFDFE
>   9300CN|CO|CP|AY1AZFAA4
>
> *****---there is no response from the server after this line----*********

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket pingSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            pingSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.103",6001);
            out = new PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }

        out.println("9300CN|CO|CP|AY0AZFAA5\n");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.println("9300CN|CO|CP|AY0AZFAA5\n");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.println("9300CN|CO|CP|AY0AZFAA5\n");
        out.flush();
/**** server not responding after this *************/
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.println("9300CN|CO|CP|AY0AZFAA5\n");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.close();
        in.close();
        pingSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: first, remove the "throws IOException" from main and extend your try catch block to cover all your main method, then print exception stack trace. also, add your server's code

Comment: What code are you running on the server?

Comment: There is no code on the server... It is simple application.. That is sending and transmitting messages... I added try{} catch{}.. There is no exception